# Buildings height extraction

Tags: qgis, building-heights

I am a QGIS new user and I want to extract the buildings height of a territory. I clipped the raster with the LiDar informations with the buildings polygons; after I have extract the contours level inside each polygon.

Now I want to extract the maximum value (top of the roof) and the minimum value (base of the roof) and assign them to each polygon as attribute. How can I do it?

Comment: Do you have the unfiltered LiDAR information? Can you provide information regarding the LiDAR information you are using? Where was it sourced from? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Zonal Statistics](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_zonal_statistics.html) built in plugin.

raster>zonal statistics>zonal statistics.

Select the raster with the height data, and the vector layer with the building information.

[image: Zonal Statistics]